# Issue when trying to create AngularFireStorageReference using variable

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

When creating a storage reference using example code below, I have no issue. However, when I replace "1234" with this.id I get the below issue in screenshot. How do I fix this? All documentation I have read online indicates that this should be working.

```
export class NewListComponent implements OnInit {

uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
downloadURL: Observable<string>;
uploadProgress: Observable<number>;
ref: AngularFireStorageReference;
task: AngularFireUploadTask;
uploadState: Observable<string>;
id:string;
imgObsArray: Observable<string>[] = new Array();

  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


uploadFile(event) {

this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
this.ref = this.afStorage.ref("1234");
this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
this.uploadState = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(s => s.state));
this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();

  this.ref.getDownloadURL()
  .subscribe(avatarUrl => {
      this.downloadURL = avatarUrl
      this.imgObsArray.push(this.downloadURL)
     console.log(avatarUrl + " This is the avatarUrl " + this.downloadURL + " This is the downloadURL ");
  }, (error) => {
     console.error(error);
  });

}

}
```

Error

[image]

UPDATED CODE BASED ON FEEDBACK

```
uploadFile(event) {
const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);

console.log(id + " THIS IS THE RANDOM ID")

this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(id);

this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);

this.uploadState = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(s => s.state));

this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges(); 

this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe( 
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.ref.getDownloadURL())).subscribe(); 

this.downloadURL.pipe(
    filter( url => url !== undefined),
    tap(avatarUrl => { this.imgObsArray.push(avatarUrl),
    console.log(avatarUrl + " This is the avatarUrl " + avatarUrl + " This is the downloadURL "); }),
    catchError( error => { 
    console.error(error); 
    return Observable.throw(error);}
)).subscribe();

}
```

[image]

Comment: does your code work if "x8d2nlj7yrl" instead of "1234"? If it does, then there could be problem with toString(radix: number) function.

Comment: @KiraAG using "x8d2nlj7yrl" instead of "1234" my code still works.

Comment: ok. So problem might be because of this reference of TS. Either try `const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);`  or `this.afStorage.ref(Math.random().toString(36).substring(2));`

Comment: This is 404 error and its coming from server . Error message is pretty clear that the id you are passing is invalid.

Comment: Thank you @KiraAG, I have debugged further and I think the problem is actually that given I am uploading the file and then trying to get the download URL in the same function and it is happening asynchronously, it is returning a 404 as the file is yet to be uploaded. The reason I think is because is that first try returns a 404, second try, third try etc. all works fine. Is there a way to fix this???

Comment: Its is mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#monitoring-upload-percentage) that you should access the download url on the complete of snapshot changes. `

Comment: SO your code might look like this                                      `this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();
 this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe( finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.ref.getDownloadURL() )).subscribe();                                                             

  this.downloadURL.pipe(tap(avatarUrl => {
  this.imgObsArray.push(avatarUrl)
     console.log(avatarUrl + " This is the avatarUrl " + avatarUrl + " This is the downloadURL ");
  }),
  catchError( error => {
     console.error(error);
  })).subscribe();`

Comment: Let me know if it works, I will put it as an answer.

Comment: @KiraAG thanks heaps, it seems to be working mostly now, but is still throwing a ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined on the this.download.pipe

Comment: @Rogerto try adding `filter(url => url !== undefined)` before `tap`. and also check the whether  `this.download.pipe` is correct. Cuz It might be `this.downloadURL.pipe`.

Comment: thanks again @KiraAG, but still not working, I have updated my original question above to include updated code based on your feedback, if you can spot any errors with what I have done greatly appreciated

Comment: @Rogerto Also if possible, add the console error screenshot too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183869/discussion-between-kiraag-and-rogerto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer, You should retrieve the downloadUrl on the finalize of snapshot changes as mentioned in storage docs. To resolve the pipe error,  its better to move this.downloadUrl subscription to ngOnInit.

PS: After further discussion , it seems that ref.getDownloadUrl can initially return null.